# Problems getting LEFT OUTER JOIN to work

Tags: mysql, sql, join, outer-join

I thought I understood how left outer joins work, but I have a situation that is not working, and I'm not 100% sure if the way I have my query structured is incorrect, or if it's a data issue.

For background, I have the following MySQL table structures:

```
mysql> describe achievement;
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | varchar(64)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| game_id     | varchar(10)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name        | varchar(64)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| description | varchar(255)         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| image_url   | varchar(255)         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| gamerscore  | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| hidden      | tinyint(1)           | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| base_hidden | tinyint(1)           | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
mysql> describe gamer_achievement;
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| game_id        | varchar(10)         | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| achievement_id | varchar(64)         | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| gamer_id       | varchar(36)         | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| earned_epoch   | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| offline        | tinyint(1)          | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As for the data, this is what I have populated here (only pertinent columns included for brevity):

```
+----+------------+------------------------------+
| id | game_id    | name                         |
+----+------------+------------------------------+
| 1  | 1480656849 | Cluster Buster               |
| 2  | 1480656849 | Star Gazer                   |
| 3  | 1480656849 | Flower Child                 |
| 4  | 1480656849 | Oyster-meister               |
| 5  | 1480656849 | Big Cheese of the South Seas |
| 6  | 1480656849 | Hexic Addict                 |
| 7  | 1480656849 | Collapse Master              |
| 8  | 1480656849 | Survivalist                  |
| 9  | 1480656849 | Tick-Tock Doc                |
| 10 | 1480656849 | Marathon Mogul               |
| 11 | 1480656849 | Millionaire Extraordinaire   |
| 12 | 1480656849 | Grand Pearl Pooh-Bah         |
+----+------------+------------------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
+----------------+------------+--------------+---------+
| achievement_id | game_id    | earned_epoch | offline |
+----------------+------------+--------------+---------+
| 1              | 1480656849 |            0 |       1 |
| 2              | 1480656849 |            0 |       1 |
| 3              | 1480656849 |            0 |       1 |
| 4              | 1480656849 |   1149789371 |       0 |
| 7              | 1480656849 |   1149800406 |       0 |
| 8              | 1480656849 |            0 |       1 |
| 9              | 1480656849 |   1149794790 |       0 |
| 10             | 1480656849 |   1149792417 |       0 |
+----------------+------------+--------------+---------+
8 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

In this particular case, the `achievement` table is the "master" table and will contain the information that I always want to see.  The `gamer_achievement` table only contains information for achievements that are actually earned.  For any particular game for any particular gamer, there can be any number of rows in the `gamer_achievement` table - including none if no achievements have been earned for that game.  For example, in the sample data above, achievements with ids 5, 6, 11, and 12 have not been earned.

What I currently have written is

```
select a.id,
       a.name,
       ga.earned_epoch,
       ga.offline
from   achievement a 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN gamer_achievement ga 
       ON (a.id = ga.achievement_id and a.game_id = ga.game_id)
where  ga.gamer_id = 'fba8fcaa-f57b-44c6-9431-4ab78605b024' 
       and a.game_id = '1480656849'
order by convert (a.id, unsigned)
```

but this is only returning the full information for those achievements that have actually been earned - the unearned achievement information from the right side table (`gamer_achievement`) is not being show with the NULL values as I would expect from this type of query.  This is what I am expecting to see:

```
+----+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+
| id | name                          | earned_epoch | offline |
+----+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+
| 1  | Cluster Buster                |            0 |       1 |
| 2  | Star Gazer                    |            0 |       1 |
| 3  | Flower Child                  |            0 |       1 |
| 4  | Oyster-meister                |   1149789371 |       0 |
| 5  | Big Cheese of the South Seas  |         NULL |    NULL |
| 6  | Hexic Addict                  |         NULL |    NULL |
| 7  | Collapse Master               |   1149800406 |       0 |
| 8  | Survivalist                   |            0 |       1 |
| 9  | Tick-Tock Doc                 |   1149794790 |       0 |
| 10 | Marathon Mogul                |   1149792417 |       0 |
| 11 | Millionaire Extraordinaire    |         NULL |    NULL |
| 12 | Grand Pearl Pooh-Bah          |         NULL |    NULL |
+----+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What am I missing here?  From what I understand, the basic query LOOKS right to me, but I'm obviously missing some piece of critical information.

Comment: +1 Nice detailed question .....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Many have answered, but I'll try too and hopefully lend in some more clarification.  How I have always interpreted it (and you can check so many other posts I've responded to with LEFT joins), I try to list the table I want everything from first (left side... hence read from left to right).  Then left join to the "Other" table (right side) on whatever the criteria is between them...  Then, when doing a left join, and there are additional criteria against the right side table, those conditions would stay with that join condition.  By bringing them into the "WHERE" clause would imply an INNER JOIN (must always match) which is not what you want...  I also try to always show the left table alias.field = right table alias.field to keep the correlation clear...  Then, apply the where clause to the basis criteria you want from the first table..  something like

```
select 
      a.id,
      a.name,
      ga.earned_epoch,
      ga.offline
   from   
      achievement a 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN gamer_achievement ga 
             ON a.id = ga.achievement_id
            AND a.game_id = ga.game_id
            AND ga.gamer_id = 'fba8fcaa-f57b-44c6-9431-4ab78605b024'
   where
      a.game_id = '1480656849'
   order by 
      convert (a.id, unsigned)
```

Notice the direct relation between "a" and "ga" by the common ID and game ID values, but then tacked on the specific gamer.  The where clause only cares at the outer level of achievement based on the specific game.

Comment: Was torn between your answer and the one @Benoit gave (you both got upvotes), but your clarification and discussion of "best practices" is why I put the checkmark here.  Thanks!

Comment: great answer. What most people do is `JOIN table1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id WHERE t1.game_id = t2.game_id` which is not what they want. What they want would be `JOIN table1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id AND t1.game_id = t2.game_id`.

Answer (score 9):

In the WHERE clause you discard some rows that the LEFT JOIN would have filled with NULL values. You want to put the condition `ga.gamer_id = 'fba8fcaa-f57b-44c6-9431-4ab78605b024'` inside the JOIN clause.

Another option is:

```
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM gamer_achievement
                   WHERE  ga.gamer_id = 'fba8fcaa-f57b-44c6-9431-4ab78605b024' 
                 ) ga
```

Remember that the join is performed, and at this time, NULL values come if the condition cannot be met; then the `where` filter applies.

Answer (score 3):

`WHERE` clauses filter results from the entire result set. If you want to apply a filter only to the `JOIN`, then you can add the expression to the `ON` clause.

In the following query, I've moved the filter expression that applies to the joined table (`ga.gamer_id =`) from the WHERE clause to the ON clause. This prevents the expression from filtering out rows where gamer_achievement values are NULL.

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       ga.earned_epoch,
       ga.offline
FROM   achievement a 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN gamer_achievement ga 
       ON ga.achievement_id = a.id
       AND ga.game_id = a.game_id
       AND ga.gamer_id = 'fba8fcaa-f57b-44c6-9431-4ab78605b024'
WHERE
       a.game_id = '1480656849'
ORDER BY CONVERT(a.id, UNSIGNED)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because of this line:

```
where  ga.gamer_id = 'fba8fcaa-f57b-44c6-9431-4ab78605b024'
```

If the `gamer` hasn't earned the `achievement`, the `ga.gamer_id` value will be `NULL` and not qualify for the `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the where clause is filtering out your desired results, moving it to the left join may work.

```
select a.id, 
       a.name, 
       ga.earned_epoch, 
       ga.offline 
from   achievement a  
       LEFT OUTER JOIN gamer_achievement ga  
       ON (a.id = ga.achievement_id and 
           a.game_id = ga.game_id and 
           ga.gamer_id = 'fba8fcaa-f57b-44c6-9431-4ab78605b024' and
           a.game_id = '1480656849') 
order by convert (a.id, unsigned)
```

Comment: Actually this will display a row with NULL values for every achievement of which the id is not 1480656849.